# Give subclass of QQuickItem pointer to another C++ object

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I very much want to subclass a Qt [QQuickItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qquickitem.html) class for use in QML, therefore giving it a lot of C++ logic behind the scenes. However, since QML will instantiate it and own it, not the C++ side, I do not know how (if it is possible) to pass pointers or connections between this new object and other C++ objects in the system. Is this possible?

Comment: Something like `Accessing Loaded QML Objects by Object Name` [here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a global QML object in you `main.cpp` which poins to an arbitrary QObject.

```
Brain *brain = new Brain();

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("brain", brain);
```

Now you have `brain` available globally in QML. You can pass it to a custom component, for example

```
VisibleComponent  {
    id: vico1
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Component.onCompleted: {
        vico1.setLogic(brain)
    }
}
```

This requires a `Q_INVOKABLE void setLogic(Brain* brain);` in `VisibleComponent`.

I have a running example project of this code, let me know if you need it.